# How to delete CallLogs from blackberry Device Programatically

Tags: blackberry

I use 'CallLogs.deleteCall(position,FolderType);'

But it can't delete the record.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
PhoneLogs _logs = PhoneLogs.getInstance();
int len = _logs.numberOfCalls(_logs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    _logs.deleteCall(i, _logs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);
}
```

Comment: Did you get a log or error message that might give us some clue to the problem?

Comment: PhoneLogs _logs = PhoneLogs.getInstance();
int len = _logs.numberOfCalls(_logs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);
   
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 _logs.deleteCall(i, _logs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);    
}  I write this code to delete the logs . This code will run successfully but could not delete any record.  So what's the problem

Comment: I put your code in your question. Are you running this on the simulator or an actual device? If on a device does your program have PERMISSION_PHONE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in the Blackberry Support forms and you can get a solution there. It is a thread issue and problem in the RIM API. Please follow this thread it is suggested by RIM adviser

[Deleting call logs, Waiting is the solution](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Deleting-call-logs-Waiting-is-the-solution/m-p/334753)
and

[Delete of phonelog](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Delete-of-phonelog-delete/m-p/528284#M106852)

If you have more doubts in blackberry come here i will explain [click here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3177/life-for-blackberry)